# swift UIAlertController doesn't show up when trying to record synchronously

Tags: swift, file, recording

Really simple I thought....  I want to record a file that is controlled by AlertControllers. See code below.  Problem is the alerts don't show up.  Have tried using dispatch to the main queue etc...

Ok new edits same behavior but the completion handler is getting executed. I did remove the semaphore, hoping it wasn't needed.

```
       func record_file(file:String, start_title: String, start_message: String, stop_title: String, stop_message: String, cancel:Bool=false, sender:Any)
{
    //let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let rec1_alert = UIAlertController(title: stop_title, message: stop_message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let stop_rec1_alert = UIAlertController(title: stop_title, message: stop_message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    let stop_rec1_action =  UIAlertAction(title: stop_title, style: .default, handler: nil)


    let action = UIAlertAction(title: start_title, style: .default, handler:nil)



    rec1_alert.addAction(action)

    self.present(rec1_alert, animated: true, completion:
                        {
                        self.player.startRecording(filename:  (file as NSString).lastPathComponent as String)


                        stop_rec1_alert.addAction(stop_rec1_action)
                        self.present(stop_rec1_alert, animated: true, completion: {
                            self.player.finishRecording()
                            //semaphore.signal()

                    })

    })
}
```

Comment: You have a deadlock on the main queue. `self.present` tells the run loop to present the alert controller, the *next time* the UI event loop refreshes. But before that happen, `semaphore.wait` is already executed and make your main queue to wait for a signal that never comes

Comment: Put what you want to do inside the completion handler of `self.present`

Comment: Ok so I think I tried to do what you said.....  But still not working.  Sorry I am fairly new to swift and iOS, and still need a better understanding of the handlers and completion handlers.....

Comment: Don't just put `semaphore.wait` in there.... what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Oh OK,  I want to execute another alert controller to stop the recording.  Give me a few minutes. I think I get it.

Comment: OK still having issues.....